# How to graph a tendency line in a discontinuous regression in Stata?

Tags: stata, scatter-plot

I need to show a scatter plot of a time series variable that is static in every year (the plot is actually a bunch of vertical lines). And I need to create a tendency line that shows the changes in the different time periods.

[image: here is an illustration of what I need to have]

Notice that the tendency is broken over time because of structural changes on the variable that is being measured.

The code I used was `two-way (scatter var1 var2)`. The lines were hand-drawn to show an approximate example of how the final result should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have already got a graph with line segments.

```
. webuse grunfeld

. line invest year if company == 1 ///
|| lfit invest year if company == 1 ///
|| lfit invest year if company == 1 & year < 1945, ///
lp(dash) legend(order(2 "all years" 3 "before 1945"))
```

shows some technique you may not know. The second command should be typed on one line. Omit `///` if typing interactively.

But where is the code you tried? That's expected in posts in this forum.